# How to get a list of all values of one-pair dictionaries inside a list, each dictionary having a different key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list of dictionaries, each dictionary with only one pair key-value, and each one with different keys and value, 
how to get a list of all values of the dictionaries?

example:

Given

```
my_list = [
            {'A': 'first'}, 
            {'B': 'second'}, 
            {'C': 'third'}, 
            {'D': 'fourth'}, 
            {'E': 'fifth'}, 
            {'F': 'sixth'}
          ]
```

and I want to get

> ```
> My_list_2 = [
>              'first', 
>              'second', 
>              'third', 
>              'fourth', 
>              'fifth', 
>              'sixth'
>             ]
> ```

how can I do it?

I have tryed with

```
my_list_2 = [ el.values() for el in my_list ]
```

but I get

> ```
> [dict_values(['first']),
>  dict_values(['second']),
>  dict_values(['third']),
>  dict_values(['fourth']),
>  dict_values(['fifth']),
>  dict_values(['sixth'])]
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I dismissed your suggestion without evaluating carefully. The answer you mention gives actually a solution to my problem, since the expression it suggests, i.e. `next(iter(d.values()))`, can be used to build this list comprehension: `[ next(iter(d.values())) for d in my_list]`, that is the result I seek. I might be more efficient than the solution purposed by @Suyog Shimpi, but I thing this latter answer is more clear and easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use like this

```py
my_list_2 = [ ol for el in my_list for ol in el.values() ]
```

Result would be -

```
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
My_list_2 = [v for m in my_list for k,v in m.items()]
# ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']
```